# Work with ng-disable when required field is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope

I'm having some problems to put `ng-disable` to work, so, I have this div:

```
<div>
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <div >
     <input type="number" id="field1" placeholder="field 1" ng-model="field1" min="0" required>
     <input type="date" id="field2"  ng-model="field2">
  </div>
  <button ng-disabled="field1.$valid" ng-click="submit()">OK</button>
</div>
```

I want to validate **if the field1 is empty (not filled) I want to disable the button,** so, the user can't click on it.

**How I can do that?**
I tried some ways, but anyone worked for me.

Comment: use `ng-disabled="!field1.trim().length`"

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj Sure, It worked, but, if I added a value for the field, the button not become enable to click

Comment: Check out my answer @PedroHenrique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have your HTML code inside a `form`. Click on `Run code snippet` to see it working.

```js
function ApplicationController($scope) {     
    $scope.message = "Hola Pedro Henrique!";
    $scope.submit = function(){
        console.log($scope.field1);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app ng-controller="ApplicationController" role="form" name="form1" novalidate>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
    <div>
        <input type="number" id="field1" placeholder="field 1" ng-model="field1" min="0" required>
        <input type="date" id="field2"  ng-model="field2">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form1.$invalid" ng-click="submit()">OK</button>
</form>
```